# Why am I getting an IllegalArgumentException when calling DELETE over HTTPS but not when using HTTP and not when calling GET over HTTPS?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Any thoughts on this issue would be appreciated.

I am accessing a Play Framework server's REST API with a Jersey 2.24.1 client.  Generally I can access most API endpoints (GET, POST, PUT) fine (or seemingly so):

```
Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://api.myserver.com")
                                .path("/getEndpointPath")
                                .request()
                                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "encoded auth string")
                                .get();
```

However, calls to DELETE methods will throw an exception when using HTTPS but will not fail exceptionally if the url is changed to use HTTP:

```
Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("https://api.myserver.com")
                                .path("/deleteEndpointPath")
                                .request()
                                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "encoded auth string")
                                .delete();
```

The stack trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null

    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.delete(JerseyInvocation.java:360)
    at com.signifyd.integrationTest.v2api.HttpsTest.troubleshootDelete(HttpsTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil$IgnoreIgnoredTestJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:365)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1455)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2979)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:489)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:176)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1099)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2662)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2584)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1770)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    ... 40 more
```

Also, **I can access these endpoints via HTTPS using Postman**, so it appears that the endpoints are not completely broken.

Any idea how this can happen?

**Additional Information**

The request header looks like:

```
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > DELETE https://api.myserver.com/deleteEndpointPath
1 > Authorization: Basic THSAHASDFJalkasdlgjisadjkladfsk09A==:
```

Comment: The bottom part of the stacktrace suggests that there is a redirect going on.  Is it possible to log the response(s) being sent from the Play Framework server?  Also, the second comment on [this old Java bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5069130) also suggests that a slightly-broken redirect (which Play could be generating) could be causing the problem, and that other clients may be more tolerant of such broken URLs.

Comment: can you post the Request and Response headers?

Comment: @stringy05  I am looking for a good way to capture the headers.  I installed LoggingFeature but its not reporting headers for the relevant call.

Comment: @LukeWoodward The java bug you referenced could be the problem.  I checked the Play change logs and found the following [redirect bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6366).  Unfortunately the server uses 2.2.x and the possible fix appears in 2.5.5

Comment: add one of these to get Jersey to log reqs/resp headers:    client.register(new LoggingFilter(java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));

Comment: @stringy05 Thank you, I used your filter instead of the LoggingFeature and found the request header, pasted above.  No reply header was apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and it was a simple mistake, leaving it here in case it helps anyone else.
In the code below I had omitted @PathVariable (value = "id"). Now that it's included the below works.

```
@DeleteMapping("/deletePosition/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deletePositionById(@PathVariable (value = "id") Long positionId) {
    return positionService.deletePositionById(positionId);
    
}
```